How to vertically center text of various sizes within a table row?
I have a table containing text of various sizes. The reasons for this is that I would like to vertically stretch my table to fill up an entire page, and while doing so, increasing the font size in certain cells. However, I cannot do this uniformly on the entire table. I understand that the text will be aligned on the same baseline, so I will have to adjust it, perhaps by using raisebox, or the more appropriate tabularray package. The starting-point example is from the cited answer. Preferably, I would like to see a working solution for booktabs.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\dummy}{%
  It is practically a big lie that \LaTeX\ 
  makes you focus on the content without
  bothering about the layout.%
}
\newcommand\zz{\fcolorbox{cyan3}{yellow9}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\dummy}}}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}\Huge
List of important things with unimportant remarks
\end{center}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
Name & Age & Remarks\\
\toprule
{\Huge John Doe} & 20 & This is unimportant yet long stuff I don't want to enlarge...\\
\midrule
{\Huge Jane Roe} & 30 & ...but I want it to be vertically centered in the cell\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%\caption{My data}
\end{table}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c,h]X[c]X[c]X[c]},
  stretch = 0,
  rowsep = 6pt,
  hlines = {red5, 1pt},
  vlines = {red5, 1pt},
}
  \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-a} & Hello & \Huge world & \zz \\
  \includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{example-image-b} & \Huge Hello & world & \zz \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


Edit: The following simple example illustrates the rendering of the proposed solution using \adjustbox. In particular, the vertical height of the cells are different, and some of the text is clearly misaligned.
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c]X[c]},
  rowsep = 2pt,
  hlines = {red5, 1pt},
  vlines = {red5, 1pt},
}
\adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge ooooo}\\
\adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge opopo}\\ 
\adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge obobo}\\ 
\adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge opobo}\\
\adjustbox{valign=m}{opopo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge ooooo}\\
\adjustbox{valign=m}{obobo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge ooooo}\\ 
\adjustbox{valign=m}{opobo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge ooooo}\\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


In any case, this seems to require some further fine-tuning.

Like this?

If I correctly understood what you after, than you need to move baseline to vertical center of each cells contents. For example by use adjustbox package:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[vmargin=2cm,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcommand{\dummy}{%
  It is practically a big lie that \LaTeX\ 
  makes you focus on the content without
  bothering about the layout.%
}
\newcommand\zz{\fcolorbox{cyan3}{yellow9}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{\dummy}}}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}\Huge
List of important things with unimportant remarks
    \end{center}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c,m]},
  rowsep = 6pt,
  hlines = {red5, 1pt},
  vlines = {red5, 1pt},
}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-a} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{Hello} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge world} & \zz \\
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-b} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge Hello} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{world} & \zz \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


Thanks for your answer. My eyes are not as good as they used to be, but it appears (?) that in the first line "word" is slightly down? You can see the horizontal center line in the images A and B, respectively. In hindsight, my exaples are not the best, because there are no letters which reach below the baseline, such as jg, etc. Your second line looks okayish.

@Matsmath, both rows are equal vertical centered. I suggest you to print table and than make measurement of distance by ruler. As you noted,  baseline centering also consider space for letters j, g, p etc, regardless if they are not presented in text. Better centering in table (as far as I know) can not be achieved.

Thanks again. I have checked, and there seems to be room for improvement. In particular, if you change rowsep to 2pt and remove the first and last columns, you may experiment with \adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge ooooo}\\  and \adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge opopo}\\  and \adjustbox{valign=m}{ooooo} & \adjustbox{valign=m}{\Huge opobo}\\  etc. In the very first case, the ooos are clearly not vertically centered. Furthermore, the row height depends on whether the characters extend below the baseline, e.g. if they contain q,p letters.

What improvement? Default value for rowsep is 2pt. When you omit  the first and last column, you have new, different table. It is not clear what you after. Sorry.
